# Yes/No :Is $M$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the  following statement is true /false ?

> Let $M$ be the  set of $2 \times 2$ matrices $ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ with complex entries  such that $a_{12} + \bar a_{21 }=0$. Then under usual matrix addition  and scalar multiplication,
>
> $M$ is a vector space  over $\mathbb{C}$

Note : $\bar a_{21}$  denotes the conjugate of $a_{21}$

## My attempt : I thinks yes

Here $$M_2(\Bbb{C})\sim \Bbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$$

Then  $$V=\Bigg\{ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} \in M_2(\Bbb{C}):  a_{12} + \bar a_{21 }=0\Bigg\}$$
can be written as $$\Bigg\{  (a_{11} , a_{12}, a_{21} , a_{22})\in \Bbb{C}^4: a_{12}+ \bar a_{21}=0\Bigg\}$$

Which is same as $$\Bigg\{ (a_{11} , a_{12}, a_{21} , a_{22})\in \Bbb{C}^4:\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 &0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12}\\ a_{21} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}=0\Bigg\}$$
which exactly the homogeneous solution of the system: $Ax=0$

where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} \\ a_{12}\\ a_{21} \\ a_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and so it is a subspace of $M_2(\Bbb{C}) $, which means it is a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$

Is  its true ?

Comment: No, because the condition is $a_{12}+\overline{a_{21}}=0$, not  $a_{12}+a_{21}=0$.

Comment: @Bernard  $a_{12} + \bar a_{21} = a_{12}  + a_{21}$ .every real is complex

Comment: What???????????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Counterexample*:
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&i\\i&1\end{pmatrix}$ belongs to your set. But 
$$(1+i)A=\begin{pmatrix}
1+i&-1+i\\-1+i&1+i\end{pmatrix}$$
doesn't. However, it is easy to check it is a *real* subspace.